# Adding a Fragment activity in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I want to add an activity with a fragment in existing development code but but I can't figure out how to do that Eclipse. I have created an xml-layout and a class. What should be the next steps ?

Comment: To add the support library to the project, right click the project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library

Comment: and check this out: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that should help you:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html